# Bluetooth car audio with track data

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio

I have a Droid 3 and a 2012 Toyota Camry which offers bluetooth support. Currently I find the only app that will display track information on the screen of the Camry's stereo is the default Android music player. Winamp and others don't seem able to do this.

Is this a limitation of Android? Or are there other apps that I do not know about that have the ability to transfer track information to the car stereo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature uses Bluetooth [AVRCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29), the *Audio Video Remote Control Profile*. It's used for controlling the app from the receiver (e.g. play/pause buttons on a BT headset).

AVRCP level 1.3 is possible since ICS and improved in [Jelly Bean](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/29676-avrcp-13-support-in-jelly-bean/); it allows all of 1.0 (play, pause, next,...) plus metadata information on the track itself (artist, track name, etc.). It was also backported into [CyanogenMod7.2](http://m.h-online.com/open/news/item/CyanogenMod-7-2-gets-backported-Android-4-0-features-1622898.html?from-classic=1) (Gingerbread).

Players themselves have to support AVRCP 1.3 too, I guess.

[Apollo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrew.apollo.play) might also support this. Or just search for AVRCP 1.3 in the store.

Comment: It's weird that stock music supports this and the other players don't. If nothing else this will make me more likely to upgrade once I'm eligible for a new subsidized phone.

Comment: Maybe AVRCP 1.3 support was added by Motorola for the builtin player only.

Answer (score 1):

AVRCP is not supported in most players. Mostly in the stock players and CM,s Apollo, unfortunately the stock players are crap and unusable in terms of sound quality. Double Twist player has partial support, song title shows but not album title.

Answer (score 0):

[Now Playing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.underwood.now_playing) just received support for AVRCP, in case that helps.